# How can i rotate object smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class RotateObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float turningRate = 1;

    void Awake()
    {
        fpcscript = transform.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();
        fpcscript.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0), turningRate * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Using Lerp make it rotating but with some stuttering when rotating it's not so smooth.

I also tried first to use Quaternion.RotateTowards instead Lerp but it was too slow and not smooth either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm uncertain that you were asking for a specific way;  Though in unity3d I created a basic way so that you can just attach a script and ***set the values***.
Within the inspector it should ask for values to rotate on [X, Y, Z] It uses time.deltaTime and basic ***Vector's*** that allow a ***smooth rotation***.  This is the best that I could come up with as I'm uncertain if you're asking for a specific way as I may be able to help if you do.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateObject : MonoBehaviour
{
public float RotationSpeedX;
public float RotationSpeedY;
public float RotationSpeedZ;

public void Update()
{
    Vector3 RotationSPD = new Vector3(RotationSpeedX, RotationSpeedY, RotationSpeedZ);
    Rotate_Object(RotationSPD);
}
private void Rotate_Object (Vector3 Rotation_Speed)
{
    transform.Rotate(Rotation_Speed * Time.deltaTime);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

transform.Rotate(Speed * Time.deltaTime);
use this api: Time.deltaTime will make it smooth.